# ReactJs & MSAL.js Unauthorized 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal

I have a pretty basic React App which the user can login and hit some MS Graph endpoint(s), this works great no problem once consent has been approved by the user. I also have another request firing to an anonymous Azure Function that spits back some JSON, brilliant no problem.

The issue I'm having is related to when I'm trying to make a request to an Azure Function Api that is locked down using AD with the MSAL.js lib.

I'm using https://github.com/sunilbandla/react-msal-sample.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AuthService from './services/auth.service';
import GraphService from './services/graph.service';
import HelloService from './services/hello.service';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.authService = new AuthService();
    this.graphService = new GraphService();
    this.helloService = new HelloService();
    this.state = {
      user: null,
      userInfo: null,
      apiCallFailed: false,
      loginFailed: false
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {}

  callAPI = () => {
    this.setState({
      apiCallFailed: false
    });
    this.authService.getToken().then(
      token => {
        this.graphService.getUserInfo(token).then(
          data => {
            this.setState({
              userInfo: data
            });
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.setState({
              apiCallFailed: true
            });
          }
        );
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({
          apiCallFailed: true
        });
      }
    );
  };

  callHelloAPI = () => {
    this.setState({
      apiCallFailed: false
    });
    this.authService.getToken().then(
      token => {
        this.helloService.callApi(token).then(
          data => {
            this.setState({
              userInfo: data
            });
            console.log(data);
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.setState({
              apiCallFailed: true
            });
          }
        );
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({
          apiCallFailed: true
        });
      }
    );
  };

  getTheToken = () => {
    console.log('Get Token:');
    this.authService.getToken().then(token => {
      console.log(token);
    });
  }

  logout = () => {
    this.authService.logout();
  };

  login = () => {
    this.setState({
      loginFailed: false
    });
    this.authService.login().then(
      user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log(user);
          this.setState({
            user: user
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            loginFailed: true
          });
        }
      },
      () => {
        this.setState({
          loginFailed: true
        });
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    let templates = [];
    if (this.state.user) {
      templates.push(
        <div key="loggedIn">
          <button onClick={this.callAPI} type="button">
            Call MS Graph
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.callHelloAPI} type="button">
            Call Azure Function
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.getTheToken}>
          Get The Token (JWT / Cookie)
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.logout} type="button">
            Logout
          </button>
          <h3>Hello {this.state.user.name}</h3>
          <h4>{this.state.user.displayableId}</h4>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      templates.push(
        <div key="loggedIn">
          <button onClick={this.login} type="button">
            Login with Microsoft
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (this.state.userInfo) {
      templates.push(
        <pre key="userInfo">{JSON.stringify(this.state.userInfo, null, 4)}</pre>
      );
    }
    if (this.state.loginFailed) {
      templates.push(<strong key="loginFailed">Login unsuccessful</strong>);
    }
    if (this.state.apiCallFailed) {
      templates.push(
        <strong key="apiCallFailed">Graph API call unsuccessful</strong>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">React app with MSAL.js</h1>
        </header>
        {templates}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

auth.service

```
import * as Msal from 'msal';

export default class AuthService {
  constructor() {
    let PROD_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    let redirectUri = window.location.origin;
    if (window.location.hostname !== '127.0.0.1') {
      redirectUri = PROD_REDIRECT_URI;
    }
    this.applicationConfig = {
      clientID: 'xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx',
      graphScopes: ['user.read','user.readbasic.all']
    };
    this.app = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
      this.applicationConfig.clientID,
      '',
      () => {
        // callback for login redirect
      },
      {
        redirectUri
      }
    );
  }
  login = () => {
    return this.app.loginPopup(this.applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(
      idToken => {
        const user = this.app.getUser();
        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
      () => {
        return null;
      }
    );
  };
  logout = () => {
    this.app.logout();
  };
  getToken = () => {
    return this.app.acquireTokenSilent(this.applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(
      accessToken => {
        return accessToken;
      },
      error => {
        return this.app
          .acquireTokenPopup(this.applicationConfig.graphScopes)
          .then(
            accessToken => {
              return accessToken;
            },
            err => {
              console.error(err);
            }
          );
      }
    );
  };
}
```

graph.service

```
export default class GraphService {
  constructor() {
    this.graphUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users';
  }

  getUserInfo = token => {
    const headers = new Headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });
    const options = {
      headers
    };
    return fetch(this.graphUrl, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(response => {
        throw new Error(response);
      });
  };
}
```

hello.service

```
export default class HelloService {
  constructor() {
    this.graphUrl = 'https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Hey';
  }

  callApi = token => {
    const headers = new Headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });
    const options = {
      headers
    };
    return fetch(this.graphUrl, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(response => {
        throw new Error(response);
      });
  };
}
```

Calling this **hello.service** works fine anonymously but returns a 401 when locked down by an Azure AD App. I've verified the JWT token from jwt.io also. I'm guessing the problem is an auth issue (hopefully a simple one), would an issue arise depending if the app is an Azure AD only app or a converged app? I have also enabled CORS on the function app itself.

My brain has frozen at this point & I'm not sure which direction facing. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you configured the auth on the API?

Comment: Does the token contain the right audience (aud)?

Comment: I've tried configuring the auth through the App Registration Portal & within the Azure portal but I keep coming across the same 401 problem. I'm using Fiddler to check the HTTP interactions. Here's an screenshot of the request: tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15n8xv5&s=9#.W3qmpfZFxyw

Comment: Also I'm running a Function Proxy to display the app that is stored within a Blob Storage container. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: If it's an audience token issue should the live domain be appended with https://xxx/.auth/login/aad/callback

Comment: What audience does the token have? I.e. what is the value in the `aud` claim?

Comment: In the token itself the aud is: "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com"

Comment: Right, so it is sending the Graph API token to your API. You'll most likely need to use your Id token as the access token here, and make sure your client/application id is configured as the valid audience on the API.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm having the exact same issue!

Comment: I've been trying to solve a problem similar to this for about a month now so if anyone has **any** ideas, I'm willing to try them!

Comment: I gave up on the MSAL lib (unfortunately) & went back to using the [React & ADAL.js](https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal) implementation.